# Creating a schedule task and runas domain user, "runas" is not selectable

Tags: domain, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I have a Windows 2016 domain controller. When I try to create a schedule task in group policy, the `Run as` box is not checkable:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The functionality no longer exists.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2962486/ms14-025-vulnerability-in-group-policy-preferences-could-allow-elevati  The now removed feature left an obfuscated form of the password on a world readable directory.